# Subsonic SimpleRepository problem with Category.All

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have a problem with the Create View in the SimpleRepository example in Subsonic 3. I get an error at line (28):

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("CategoryID",new SelectList(Blog.Category.All(),
"categoryid", "description")) %>
```

Basically, .All() is not known. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Not that should make a difference for this error but I am using VS2008 with the GDR installed.

This is still an issue in 3.0.0.1 (latest download) , although the download doesnt look any dif from the original release.

Comment: Looks like it might be resolved but the version available for download was the previous version (it was cached by GitHub). I will verify later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved in 3.0.0.1